# Mailto err_unknown_url_scheme

Tags: html, mobile, mailto

I did some minor work on an existing website by adding a mailto link in a form tag. The owner tried to use the mailto link by visiting the website on his phone (it is a regular website, not optimized for mobile) and kept getting the ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME message. Is there a way to fix this from the webpage? I've seen posts about changing the code in the app or whitelisting certain sites, but I only have access to the HTML website. Any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Where is my crystal ball? Maybe you could  show the mailto link here?

Comment: Sorry. Tried to edit post to add it, but it didn't save. Here it is: <form action="mailto:name@name.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mailto is a link, not a form post:

```
<a href="mailto:helpdesk@example.org?subject=a%20simple%20Question">Mail with subject filled out</a>
```

You can find examples almost anywhere.

If you want form content mailed to some address, this is usually done on the server with a script. Could be done on the client with advanced javascript.

Comment: The problem is that he has a form on the website and didn't want me to spend a lot of time or change the look of the site. Any ideas on what to do? Should I install a php script? I didn't do that originally because of the time constraint. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Time restrictions are no justification for introducing errors in a web page.